# After add transform scale, I can't set the section to center

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I don't use javascript to listen the event of resize. Is that any method to center the div?

The css structure contain 3 state. normal , under 900px, under 550px.
When the width is over 550px. I can set the section to center. When the screen is under 550px. I used scale to reduce the size and then I am unable to set it to center.

I tried change to position to fixed/relative, left/ float/transform-origin/translateX/use vw/margin/padding...
Is that I must use javascript to listen the window resize and then change the left property for the css of the section?

my website is on http://php-kkhchan.rhcloud.com

CSS:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .box {
        width: 520px;
        height: 650px;
    }

    #tabs { 
        width:520px ; height: 650px;
        position: static;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 1em;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    #tabs, .box {
        transform: scale(0.6,0.6);
        left: -14%;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <section id="tabs">
  <article class="c_tab box" id="tab0" style="background: #A9D0F5;">
    testing
  </article>
</section>
```

You can also take reference to below jsfuddle
[JSfuddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wkkhchan/ysvr09vs/)

Comment: Please post **relevant** code and not expect everyone to weed through all your markup. In addition, have you tried the `transform-origin:` property?

Comment: Thanks. I edited the post. I have tried translate() but not tried the transform-origin. I will check it.

Comment: I tried to add `transform-origin: center center`. It is not worked.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I used javascript to handle. the following is my solution.
I am not sure if it is the best solution.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width()<=550) {
        $('#tabs').trigger('customresize');
    }
});

$('#tabs').on('customresize',function(){
    myWidth=($(window).width() - 545)/2 +'px';
    $(this).css('left',myWidth);
});
```